# Error parse JSON missing comma pos <number>

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column with a varchar and want to convert it to a JSON by parse_Json. 
(*{u'meta': {u'removedAt': None, u'validation': {u'createdTime': 157....*)

When I use :

```
select get_path(PARSE_JSON(OFFER), 'field') from
```

this error occours: SQL-Fehler [100069] [22P02]: Error parsing JSON: missing colon, pos 3.

So I try to add a Colon at position 3

```
select get_path(PARSE_JSON(REPLACE (offer,'u','u:')), 'field') from
```

So this error occurred SQL-Fehler [100069] [22P02]: Error parsing JSON: misplaced colon, pos 10

By now I don't know how do handle this and the information by snowflake doesnt really help.
https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/error-error-parsing-json-missing-comma-pos-number

Thanks for your help

Comment: `{u'meta':` I think you just need to remove the `u` and have `{ 'meta':` etc. I don't think the `u` is valid JSON.

Comment: Tried it with 

select get_path(PARSE_JSON(REPLACE (offer,'u')), 'field')
from

and got this Error:
SQL-Fehler [100069] [22P02]: Error parsing JSON: unknown keyword "None", pos 28

When i used the string as a originally JSON without u it all worked. But the JSON gets a String/varchar through the Datapipline to Snowflake

Comment: Sorry, yes I missed that. You want 'null' not 'None'. I guess this was generated by simple Python code then with Python strings? Can you use Python's JSON encoder instead to regenerate the data?

Comment: I have a postgres Database and snowflake and in between an ETL, that works with python. (but i don't write any codes)
There I can do Python transformations...
So perhaps this could be a solution. 
Good hints!

Comment: I used  

`REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(offer,'None','"None"'),'u''',''''),'''','"'))`

So I get optical the result i want to have. 

{"meta": {"removedAt

It seems like I got back the JSON Stucture.


But parse_Json does not make any transforming to a JSON or the format/datatype, where i can use a code like

`offer->'meta'->'dealer'->>'name' as dealer,`

That was the way I extracted components of the term

Answer (score 2):

Your 'JSON input' is actually a Python [representation string](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) of its dictionary data structure, and is not a [valid JSON format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). While dictionaries in Python may appear similar to JSON when printed in an interactive shell, they are not the same.

To produce valid JSON from your Python objects, use the [json module's dump or dumps functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump), and then use the proper string serialized JSON form in your parse_json function.

Comment: Thanks, Harsh!
The only problem is, that I do not use Python in any way. It is only used by the datapipline automatically. 
So i don't have any chance to use "dump"

Comment: What is producing that string that you pass to your parse_json function? Is it expected to produce a JSON output that you copy from? FWIW, the Python representation string is usually parseable into a python interpreter as-is if you need to reconvert them to proper JSON outputs.

Comment: The construction is Postgres Sql (Source)
--> Adverity/Datatap (Pipeline)
--> Snowflake (Target)

Adverity/Datatap is pulling the data in a csv and then pushing it to snowflake. Think thats where the string is built. 
This provider uses python for pulling.

Comment: Thank you, I'm unfamiliar with an Adverity/Datatap solution but if your source data string looks like that its incorrectly being written, or (oppositely) the contract there isn't supposed to be JSON.

Comment: Used 

REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(offer,'None','"None"'),'u''',''''),'''','"'))
So I get optical the result i want to have. 

{"meta": {"removedAt

If i now use parse_Json I get some strange blanks, that are "growing"


But parse_Json does not make any transforming to a JSON or brings a structure, where i can use a code like

offer->'meta'->'dealer'->>'name' as dealer,

To extract components